# How to make LIKE query in mysql fast

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `article_item` which has millions of items. `article_item` has a `content` column which contains article content. I will frequently use query like `select A,B,C from article_item where content like '%TEST%'`. One way is to create index table, but there are new items inserting into `article_item` everyday. If I create an index table, I still need to do a full text search because new items are inserted. Am i right? Mysql has full text search feature. Any other solutions?

Comment: The code `content LIKE '%TEST%'` won't be able to use an index on that column AFAIK, because the pattern begins with a wildcard.  If you need this search functionality, you should consider using full text search.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question

Comment: @Strawberry But I don't know whether NLP in mysql works fine for japanese.